# How to get name of module, which controller processing request?

Tags: nestjs

I want to get name of module, which controller processing request.

```
@Get('/')
getIndex() {
  console.log('name of module');
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the name of the module?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I use one service from module in different modules. Can recognize, which module call this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the purpose behind your question, but I'll leave you some alternatives.

> First one and the dirtier. You can get the instance of the module that your productController is imported by finding it into the modules container.

```
import { Controller, Get, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModulesContainer } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/core/injector/module';

@Controller('path')
export class ProductController {
    constructor(
        private modulesContainer: ModulesContainer,
        private productService: ProductService
    ) { }


    @Get()
    findAll(@Query() dto: any) {
        let yourModule: Module; 
        this.modulesContainer.forEach((v) => {
            if(v.controllers.has(this.constructor.name)) { // in this condition, you will find your module based in the imports from it, if your controller is importe in some module it will get the module and put in "yourModule" variable.
                // Here
                yourModule= v;
            }
        });

        console.log(yourModule);
        return  this.productService.findAll();
    }

}
```

> And for a cleaner approach you can get the moduleRef in your controller

```
import { Controller, Get, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModuleRef} from '@nestjs/core';

@Controller('path')
export class ProductController {
    constructor(
        private moduleRef: ModuleRef,
        private productService: ProductService
    ) { }


    @Get()
    findAll(@Query() dto: any) {
        console.log(this.moduleRef) //your module ref
        return  this.productService.findAll();
    }

}
```

But of course depends on what's you're trying to do.

Comment: How to get current module ? If I call moduleRef, in controller module of app module. I got app module, but I want to get current module

Comment: ModulesContainer , it is all modules of app module

Comment: In the first example on the module Container you will find the first module that your Controller is imported. And in the second example is basic the same thing, but you'll get a reference of the module that your controller is imported. It's important to remember that you will get the module that your controller is imported in both of examples.